# How to extract sub-pattern from regex match

Tags: regex, powershell

when I run the below regex match command, either:

```
'abc123' -match '(\d+)|(\w+)|(abc123)|(25)'
```

or

```
[regex]::matches('abc123', '(\d+)|(\w+)|(abc123)|(25)')
```

is there a way for me to extract the matching sub-pattern? In this case it would be the third capture block: 'abc123'

Answer (score 1):

You can't get the exact regex part that matched your string as far as I'm aware, if you use a smart constructor for the Regex you can easily automate it though.

```
$ToMatch = 'abc123FOO'

$PossibleMatches = @('\d+','\w+','abc123.+','25')
$JoinOn = ')|('

$Regex = "($($PossibleMatches -join $JoinOn))"

$CaughtGroup = [Regex]::Matches($ToMatch,$Regex).Groups | ? {$_.Success -and $_.Name -ne '0'}
$CaughtIndex = [int]$CaughtGroup.Name
$CaughtMatch = $PossibleMatches[$CaughtIndex]

"Matched Group $($CaughtIndex) '$($CaughtMatch)'"
```

will give you

```
Matched Group 2 'abc123.+'
```

if this isn't ok for you (i.e. you have wildly varied regex etc.) you might want to do break up the program flow and try match it against an array of possible ones first?

Comment: This will give you the matched string, not the actual pattern it was matched on.

Comment: @M.K. ah you're looking to see which of the groups it was caught on?

Comment: @M.K. updated, hopefully this at least points you in the right direction.

Comment: thank you! Yes, I guess I will just use this parallel approach - matching an index back to pattern array.

Comment: @M.K. great, it's not clean but it does work at least, glad I could help.